# pyglet: synchronise event with frame drawing

Tags: pyglet

The default method of animation is to have an independent timer set to execute at the same frequency as the frame rate. This is not what I'm looking for because it provides no guarantee the event is actually executed at the right time. The lack of synchronisation with the actual frame drawing leads to occasional animation jitters. The obvious solution is to have a function run once for every frame, but I can't find a way to do that. on_draw() only runs when I press a key on the keyboard. Can I get on_draw() to run once per frame, synchronised with the frame drawing?

Answer (score 0):

The way to do this is to use pyglet.clock.schedule(update), making sure vsync is enabled (which it is by default). This ensures on_draw() is run once per frame. The update function passed to pyglet.clock.schedule() doesn't even need to do anything. It can just be blank. on_draw() is now being executed once per frame draw, so there's no point in having separate functions both of which are being executed once per frame drawing. It would have been a lot nicer if there were just an option somewhere in the Window class saying on_draw() should be drawn once per second, but at least it's working now.

I'm still getting bad tearing, but that's a bug in pyglet on my platform or system. There wasn't supposed to be any tearing.

Comment: Are you sure that's the only time on_draw gets called?  Wouldn't resizing or moving the window cause on_draw to be called?